# AWS MariaDB RDS stalls while upgrading

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, rds, upgrade

Our RDS database has been in state 'Upgrading' for over 5 hours.
It appears it was applying an `Automatic minor version upgrade to mariadb 10.4.26`
I cannot connect to the database in any way; I can only view `error/mysql-error-running.log` which displays this:
[error/mysql-error-running.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JJgK.png)

It appears the only option right now is to restore to the latest backup, but I don't know if this will leave the database in an unstable/incomplete state.

Is there something else I could check or do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the storage space; it was below 10% which wasn't enough for the update.
The database eventually came back but apparently lost data, so we did restore from the latest backup.